# How to create array of pointers pointing to the whole array and assign 2D array implicitly?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, 2d

[image]In the picture above I have declared(implicit) pointer pointing to the whole array, all I want to know is that how could I declare array of such pointers and how could I access elements of 2D array as I have done in case of a single array. Note that the declaration must be implicit. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC9Je.png)

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `int (*ptr)[]` is that is points to `int[]` which is *incomplete* type. Pointers to incomplete types cannot be dereferenced. Moreover `sizeof *ptr` will not work therefore the compiler cannot compute an address of `ptr[1]`. You must use a complete type. I see three alternatives:

Use automatic 2d array.

```
int ptr[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {10,20,30}};
```

Use a pointer to a complete type and a compound literal

```
int (*ptr)[3] = (int[][3]) { {1,2,3}, {10,20,30}};
```

Use an array of pointers filled with compound literals of 1D arrays.

```
int *ptr[] = { (int[]){1,2,3}, (int[]) { 10, 20, 30} };
```

Comment: Ok, but isn't there any declaration statement so that I could just declare array of such pointers pointing to whole 1D Array? It is because in case I have several 2D arrays and for each I have to declare pointer variable and assign this is quite boring and bad practice right?

Comment: @AnupAdhikari, you could try `int *ptr = (int*)(int[][3]) { ... }` and access it as `ptr[i]`. It should let you create a 1D view of the 2D array